# Heisenberg algebra and other Lie algberas

Tags: lie-algebras

Is there a sub Lie algebra $K$ such that for an ideal $M$ of a heisenberg algebra $H$,
 $H=K+M$ and $K\cap M=0$ ($M$ has a complement in $H$)?

Is there a class of Lie algebras such every ideal  $M$ has a complement?

Yours,